# Erlang: proplists:get_value/2 or pattern matching?

Tags: erlang

I have a list of tuples that has always the same form (i.e. the tuples come always in the same order):

```
1> L = [{a, 1}. {b,2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}].
```

Knowing that the list has only a few elements, what is the best way to extract the values associated to the keys?

Suppose the list is passed as argument to a function, to extract the values should I use:

```
proplists:get_value(a, L).
proplists:get_value(b, L).
...
proplists:get_valus(d, L).
```

Or should I simply use pattern matching as:

```
[{a, 1}. {b,2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}] = L.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really know your lists is in same form pattern matching is simplest

```
[{a, A}, {b, B}, {c, C}, {d, D}] = L,
```

you can compare it with following

```
[A, B, C, D] = [ proplists:get_value(X, L) || X <- [a,b,c,d] ],
```

or

```
A = proplists:get_value(a, L),
B = proplists:get_value(b, L),
C = proplists:get_value(c, L),
D = proplists:get_value(d, L),
```

or

```
[A, B, C, D] = [ V || Key <- [a,b,c,d], {K, V} <- L, K =:= Key ],
```

Pattern matching will be also fastest. You can also use `lists:keyfind/3` which is implemented as Bif and is way faster than `proplist:get_value/2` but it doesn't matter for short lists.